# Multiple time execution bypass

Tags: php, constructor, scope, php-5.3, hierarchy

I have the follow (sample) code:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new Bar();
        $this->baz = new Bazr();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $baz = $this->baz->alert();
    }
}

class Baz extends Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function alert() {
        echo('Hello!');
    }
}

new Foo();
```

Which will generate an `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`. What I want is, exactly this, ofcourse with different code and no errors.

What I want is one way to know when my instance is already created and not allow more instances of same object, avoiding circular reference.

Learned about Singletom, but, nothing worked. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement dependence Injection is the solution:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = new Bar(new Baz());
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function __construct($baz = null) {
        $this->baz = $baz;
        $this->baz->alert();
    }
}

class Baz {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function alert() {
        echo('Hello!');
    }
}

new Foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of Foo calls the constructor of Bar which calls the constructor of Foo which calls the constructor of Bar... you get the idea. After 100 times it tells you it's dizzy.  Don't create a circular reference like that.

Comment: Yes yes, I know about the error, and how it's occour. What I want is one way to know when my instance is already created and not allow more instances of same object, avoiding circular reference.

Comment: Richard Brightwell, thanks for help, learned more about Dependence Injection wich solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand why you need all this? If only because to get methods of Bar/Baz in class Foo, then you can use:

```
class Foo {
   public function __construct() {
      Bar::init();
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function init() {
      Baz::alert();
   }
}

class Baz extends Foo {
   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function alert() {
      echo 'Hello!';
   }
}

new Foo();
```

Comment: Because this is a sample class. But, if I have a class which fetch config file. I don't want every extended class to fetch it again, but, want they use the config object with already fetched data. (this is one of many use case)

Comment: B7ackAnge7z Thanks for help, learned more about Dependence Injection wich solved my problem.